# Publically declared variables are not passing values to another form

Tags: vb.net, variables, public

i have multiple forms in my vb project. Form1 is a startup form. There is a variable, that is passing integer value to Form2. I added Form3 to the project and made it as startup form. Then i deleted it from the project and again made Form1 as startup form. But, since then the variable on Form1 is not passing its integer value to Form2. I messed up with my project. Can anybody help ???

IN FORM 1

```
 Public i as integer
 Private Sub btn_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btn.Click
     i = 1
     dim nf as new form2
     nf.showdialog(me)
 end sub
```

IN FORM 2

```
 Private Sub Form2_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
     msgbox(form1.i)
 end sub
```

But the msgbox prints value '0'

Comment: Helping you, without the code that _pass_ your variable from Form1 to Form2, it is really difficult.

Comment: i am not passing variable i am just passing its value to another form by declaring it public in form1

Comment: From the closing reason list: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: there is code (example). Now can you help ?

Comment: I cannot reproduce the problem as described. Are you sure you have the correct control is "btn"? It isn't very descriptive, so if you had more than one button of Form1, maybe it got confused with another one, like "btn2". Does Form1 show as the startup form when you run the program? Also, if you haven't already, please use [Option Strict On](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zcd4xwzs.aspx) - it might point out something amiss.

Answer (score 0):

Ok Friends thanks for your help. But, i solved it myself.

IN FORM 1

```
  Private Sub btn_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btn.Click
       dim nf as new form2
       nf.f2int = 1
       nf.showdialog(me)
  end sub
```

IN FORM 2

```
  Public Property f2int as Integer
  Private Sub Form2_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
       msgbox(f2int)
  end sub
```

Comment: This may do what you want, it doesn't use the process that you describe.  And it continues to hint that you don't understand how the constructor is operating.  Just heads up, before this question gets deleted.

Comment: My knowledge is not as good as yours. Thats why i am here so that i can learn something from knowledgeable persons like you.

Comment: That's good, but it looks like you need a basic tutorial to begin with.  Which is beyond the scope of what we can do here.